# Generate an url in ASP.NET MVC outside a view or controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I follow the article ["Simulate a Windows Service using ASP.NET to run scheduled jobs"](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12117/Simulate-a-Windows-Service-using-ASP-NET-to-run-sc) on CodeProject, and in the part "Store item in cache again upon expire" I need to hit a page of my application.

Instead of hard writing the url, I wanted to generate it with the Asp.Net MVC UrlHelper but it seams that it required some instances that I don't have access in this context, because it's not in a Controller or a View.

Is it possible or is there another solution?

EDIT:

Sadly [HttpContext.Current is not accessible in CacheItemRemovedCallBack](http://forums.asp.net/t/1735291.aspx).
So the only solution appears to store the value needed (Url.Host) in the Application_Start method in order to build the full url later.

Comment: did you try HttpContext.Current.Request?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Url.Action method with the following parameters:

```
@Url.Action("Index", "Home", routeValues, Request.Url.Scheme)
```

or

```
new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Request.RequestContext).Action("Index", "Home", routeValues, Request.Url.Scheme)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not in a View, so I can't use the @Url helper neither the Request  property.

Comment: @JérémieBertrand Can you reach the HttpContext instance?

Comment: Good idea. I can't try right now but normally I can use it.

Comment: This won't work if you are out of a request (e.g., scheduled job)

Comment: @Timotei You will see that many of the classes in ASP.NET MVC will not work outside of the context of a web applicaiton.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own instance of UrlHelper.
For this, you need to have an access to current http request.
This could be achieved using static instance of HttpContext : HttpContext.Current:

```
new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext).Action("action");
```

Comment: This won't work if you are out of a request (e.g., scheduled job)

Answer (score 0):

[https://www.codemag.com/Article/1312081/Rendering-ASP.NET-MVC-Razor-Views-to-String][1]

check this for complete description how to do this

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)